# The Command Text property has not been properly initialized

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

I have a problem when I tried adding image on my Insert statement. The message

> The Command Text property has not been properly initialized

appeared. I tried searching for solutions and still I have no clue how to solve it.

Here's the code:

```vb
Public Sub Insertplayer()
    dbconn.ConnectionString = "server='" & My.Settings.ip & "';port=3306; user id='" & My.Settings.uid & "';password='" & My.Settings.pwd & "'; database= '" & My.Settings.db & "';"
    dbcomm.Connection = dbconn
    fname = imageurltxt.Text
    Dim Content As Byte() = ImageToStream(fname)
    Try
        dbconn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "INSERT INTO `player`(`ID`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Gender`, `Date_of_Birth`, `Civil_Status`, `Nationality`, `Address`, `Status', `Picture`) VALUES('" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "', @Pic)"
        dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic", Content)
        dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(query, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader
        dbread.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        dbconn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
Private Function ImageToStream(ByVal fileName As String) As Byte()
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream()
tryagain:
    Try
        Dim image As New Bitmap(fileName)
        image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    Catch ex As Exception
        GoTo tryagain
    End Try
    Return stream.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: You should never, ever concat strings to make SQL - *all* the fields shuld use SQL Parameters and do not use global DB objects.  `GoTo` is a very bad idea.

Comment: Initialize it like this  `dbcomm.CommandType = query` before calling dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins - It should be `dbcomm.CommandText = query`.

Comment: @AlexanderHiggins I tried your suggestion well the error change to `Conversion from string “INSERT INTO `player`(`ID`, `First” to type 'Integer' is not valid`

Comment: Yup you can't use `+` to combine strings use `&` instead. `+` is trying to convert the string to an integer and add them as an arithmetic operation.

Comment: I changed all the`+` to `&` still the same error

Answer (score 1):

You are calling

```
dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

before setting the query in any way. Your insert statement is only available as content of a string variable named `query` at that point.

It's not clear where the variable `dbcomm` comes from in your code sample.

Comment: thanks for a fast response dbcomm is my MySqlCommand

Comment: Yes I saw that, but you initialize it with `dbcomm = new MySqlCommand(query, dbconn)` after you use it ...

Answer (score 0):

You've called `dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()` before you set the command text (which happens on the line that says `dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(query, dbconn)`

INSERT queries should not be ExecuteReader()ed - it looks like you've been trying a few ways to get it working, trial and error, and now have old junk code left in there..

Here is the code in a correct order:

**WARNING FOR FUTURE VISITORS: DO NOT COPY OR REUSE THIS CODE. It's a particularly terrible way to do database access.** *Later in this post I plead with the OP to dump it and start over using a proper database access library.*

```
    dbconn.Open()
    Dim query As String
    query = "INSERT INTO `player`(`ID`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Gender`, `Date_of_Birth`, `Civil_Status`, `Nationality`, `Address`, `Status', `Picture`) VALUES('" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "', @Pic)"
    dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(query, dbconn)
    dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pic", Content)
    dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    dbconn.Close()
```

All this should be in a Try Catch, though putting the dbConn.Close() in a Finally is a good idea. You might want to check the connection state before you close it (in case it failed to open, throwing an exception) - you don't want the call to fail

As an aside, **please please consider throwing all this code away and using an object-relational mapper like nHibernate, Entity Framework, Datasets** etc. In this day and age (i.e. the last 10 years) nobody should be writing low level database code that opens/closes conenctions and inserts data by having strings full of SQL in your business logic code.. All that is handled by frameworks now, that know your objects in your app, and manage the data in the database for you. It's not cool to write you own database code for similar reasons that nobody writes assembly language or other low level guff any more; it opens the app up to huge security problems and results in poor quality code that's hard to maintain and develop

Addendum: As Bugs has pointed out below, (and why I'm recommending you hand all this off to a library dedicated to doing data access) **the way this SQL is written is truly terrible, and a massive security risk**. A carefully placed apostrophe in any one of your text boxes, followed by some specially crafted SQL and an attacker can erase your entire database, dump its contents and so on.

Comment: I remove the Execute Reader a new error arises `Index and Length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name:length` then when I remove the `dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()` the error is gone but the data that I inputed has not been recorded in the database. and another question in `dbcomm.Close()` did you mean `dbconn.Close()`?

Comment: The new error you're seeing is the result of a call to Some `string.Substring()`, probably nothing to do with your db code. Removing the call to ExecuteNonQuery will indeed result in nothing being inserted to the db, for the same reason that putting a DVD in the player but not pressing play button will mean the DVD doesn't play.. executeNonQuery is the thing that executes the insert query. See my note about using Entity Framework; we don't do database access at these low levels any more; you're following a tutorial from the 90's

Comment: Whilst I appreciate you are trying to help I would also look to **improve** code. As it stands this is open to SQL injection and that should be addressed in your post within the code. It's worth considering that users will come, not read the text and just copy the code in the hope it works

Comment: @Bugs - I've tried leading that particular horse to water many times, in thousands of places all over the internet. It doesn't drink. No-one will come here and copy this code and use it unchanged because it will certainly not apply to their situation. I could parameterise it all for him, but two things prevent me taking the effort: 1) anyone who then DID come and copy it would be just as likely to erase all my good intentions and fill their version of the code with string concat and 2) i'd be doing his work for him. People come to SO because they want answers, not educating (alas)

Comment: @CaiusJard I agree, which is why I didn't downvote but I much prefer making stronger code _just in case_. A visitor could come and replicate at least the style of the code. I wouldn't want that.

Comment: I totally agree with all your sentiments; one of the things I despair about SO so much is that the entire site is geared towards rewarding the shitty contributions while the people with the problems generally are just looking to get over the "make it" hurdle in "make it, make it right, make it fast" and leave it at that :). I'll meet you half way and make a stronger argument for future visitors :)